# как убрать в смещение текстового курсора в TextBox при замене точки на запятую. (C#, WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf

В WPF добавил обработчик TextChanged для замены точки на запятую при вводе значения, но столкнулся с другой проблемой, когда ставлю точку, то она меняется на запятую и текстовый курсор уходит в самое начало строки и нужно его перемещать обратно в конец числа и продолжать вводить значение, мне кажется это не очень правильно и удобно, подскажите как исправить смещение текстового курсора?

```
private void A_text_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
 {
     string str = A_text.Text;
     if (str.Contains("."))
     {
         string s = str.Replace(".", ",");
         A_text.Clear();
         A_text.AppendText(str.Replace(".", ","));
     }
 }
```

Comment: Очень, очень плохое решение. Знаете почему? А потому что это "раздражающий фактор". Вот представьте вы в Visual Studio пишете код, хотите в одном месте поставить запятую, а вам студия автоматом меняет на то, что вы может быть даже и не хотели видеть, или может даже ставить, согласитесь, вас такое удивит, а через пару дней использования взбесит. Хотите корректный ввод - оповестите, выделите каким либо образом, но не лезьте в работу пользователя. В вашем случае достаточно привязать `TextBox` к `double` (или какой там тип у вас), все, WPF сам подсветит если надо и сам преобразует текст в число.

Comment: там поля куда необходимо вводить значения для расчета, хотел, что бы при вводе пользователь не думал ставить ему запятую или точку, а автоматически подставлялась запятая и не нужно было выводить сообщения о некорректно веденном сообщении

Comment: Просто привяжитесь, все. Если пользователь введет неверное значение, поле подсветится красным, этого достаточно для вашего случая. Почему подставлять запятую плохо - я написал выше.

Answer (score 0):

Вы должны сохранить `SelectionStart` свойство в переменной, а затем при срабатывание условий и правок текста установить для SelectionStart  значение, указанное в переменной. Тем самым вы вернете курсор в любую позицию где он до этого был.

```
private void A_text_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var cursorPosition = A_text.SelectionStart; // сохраняем текущую позицию курсора
        if (A_text.Text.Contains("."))
        {
            A_text.Text = A_text.Text.Replace(".", ",");
            A_text.SelectionStart = cursorPosition; // устанавливаем курсор в нужную позицию
        }
    }
```